# Can I listen to the children property in $ref

Tags: vue.js

if an element renders its children later and I have a ref to the element, can I listen to changes to the children property?

```
 <element ref="parent">
    <child-to-be-loaded-later />
 </element>

 watchers: {
    '$refs.parent.children'() {
       // do stuff here 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) on the template ref's element to monitor its child list:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <MyList ref="list">
      <li v-for="i in count">item {{ i }}</li>
    </MyList>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()
    this._observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
      mutationList.forEach(mutation => {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
          console.log('children added/removed', { added: mutation.addedNodes, removed: mutation.removedNodes})
        }
      })
    })

    this._observer.observe(this.$refs.list.$el, { childList: true })
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    this._observer.disconnect()
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this._observer.disconnect()
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-mutation-observer?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Thanks it works! I was trying to use a watcher on '$refs.list.childList' and it wouldn't work - wasn't sure why

Comment: `$refs.list.childList` is not reactive, which is why you can't watch it.